# Running grunt-spritesheet gives error "grunt.spritesheet requires a sprites and sheet property"

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, sprite-sheet

I just installed grunt spritesheet onto my Windows system, and when I try to run the package, I get an error for this task: **"grunt.spritesheet requires a sprites and sheet property"**.

The package looks loaded correctly, and runs with all of the other tasks with grunt. I have the Python2.7 and Cairo dependencies loaded as well.

In my main gruntfile (which already has require, jshint, and compass running fine), I added:

```
spritesheet: {
  // An array of filename / source images array pairs. The basename of the sprite file
  // is also prefixed to the CSS classes.
  sprites: {
    "images/icons/sprite.png": ['images/icons/*.png']
  },
  // The destination for the build stylesheet
  sheet: "scss/homepsprite.css"
}
```

So, the properties "sprites" and "sheet" are clearly there. Is there something else that I'm missing? The package is loading fine with the rest of the grunt modules... I have

```
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-spritesheet');
```

in my gruntfile as well as

```
 grunt.registerTask("default", ["jshint", "requirejs:dev", "compass:dev", "spritesheet"]);
```

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Here's a link to the plugin package: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-spritesheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grunt-spritesheet is a [multitask](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registermultitask) which @implicitly iterates over all of its named sub-properties@.

you could see that grunt is probably trying to run "sprites" and "sheet" as a task:

```
Running "spritesheet:sprites" (spritesheet) task
```

that means that the documentation is somewhat not so clear, and you need a "name" for your task which could basically be anything (i use `generate` here):

```
spritesheet: {
  generate: {
    // An array of filename / source images array pairs. The basename of the sprite file
    // is also prefixed to the CSS classes.
    sprites: {
      "images/icons/sprite.png": ['images/icons/*.png']
    },
    // The destination for the build stylesheet
    sheet: "scss/homepsprite.css"
  }
}
```

the output should now be:

```
Running "spritesheet:generate" (spritesheet) task
```